# Strange Integer.parseInt exception

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "Thread-2"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "3"

```
 int test = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
```

This is the error I keep getting when I'm trying to convert "3" to an integer. Well I'm receiving this "3" through a RS-232 port, so maybe this is what is causing the error.

If anybody has any idea what could be causing this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the data type of result[0]? If it's a string, are you sure there are no spaces or new lines around it?

Try `result[0].trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the char values of `result[0]` when this occurs. It might be possible that this "3" is in fact not the ASCII character '3' but some strange Unicode character that just *looks* like a 3.